# What is the exact problem of this code in Python?

Tags: python

I found a problem which I cannot solve on my own and when I did my research - answers are not unanimous.

Consider the following python code:

```
rooms = {1: 'Foyer', 2: 'Conference Room'}
room = input('Enter the room number: ')
if not room in rooms:
    print('Room does not exist.')
else:
    print("The room name is " + rooms[room])
```

The program fails to find the rooms, but when we convert room variable into **int** (like below) program works fine.

```
 rooms = {1: 'Foyer', 2: 'Conference Room'}
 room = int(input('Enter the room number: '))
 if not room in rooms:
     print('Room does not exist.')
 else:
     print("The room name is " + rooms[room])
```

A lot of people says the problem is **invalid syntax**, but in my opinion it's more like **mistmatched data type**. I don't get any errors in that code. My question is why do most people think this is **invalid syntax**.  What do you think?

Comment: what error do you get when you run it - post the full traceback.

Comment: Who says that? If the interpreter does not raise a `SyntaxError`, it is valid syntax, plain and simple. I am sure you are getting a `KeyError` in the first version, and that stems from a wrong type.

Comment: In this case, it definitely is more of a mismatched data type issue and *valid* syntax, however there is no error handling involved

Comment: If it contained invalid syntax, it would not run at all. Who are these lots of people?

Comment: Your dictionary keys are integers and input converts it to string.

Comment: "A lot of people say this is invalid syntax". It doesn't matter what people say. What does your python interpreter say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct and the ones who told you it was a syntax error, it isn't. It is exactly the "mismatched data type" since the keys on the variable "**rooms**" are integers, but the user input or the variable "**room**" is specifically not an integer or a number. In other words, the user input returns a string and the "**rooms**" variable keys are integers which create a mismatched data type when matched together by an if statement and can probably cause confusion. To prevent this, make sure to see if both values that you're gonna be comparing are the same data types.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with wondercricket...no error handling. rather than converting to int in the original input, if you move it further down, you could use it to handle the usecase of a string (invalid) input...

```
rooms = {1: 'Foyer', 2: 'Conference Room'}
room = input('Enter the room number: ')

try: 
    if int(room) in rooms:
        print("The room name is " + rooms[int(room)])
    else:
        print("could not find a room based on the number you entered...please try again")
except:
        print('Please enter the room number as a number')
```